# how do you properly use a pipe with lua to get the output of a program?

Tags: lua, posix, pipe, system-calls

I am using Lua with the luaposix library to get the the output of some commands, and sometimes send some too. I am using this code, or variants of this to do my work, but I sometimes get stuck at `posix.wait(cpid)` or sometimes the command doesn't seem to finish.

```
-- returns true on connected, else false
function wifi.wpa_supplicant_status()
    -- iw dev wlan0-1 link
    local r,w = posix.pipe()
    local cpid = posix.fork()
    if cpid == 0 then --child writes to pipe
        --close unused read end
        local devnull = posix.open("/dev/null", posix.O_RDWR)
        posix.close(r)
        posix.dup2(devnull, 0)
        posix.dup2(w, 1)
        posix.dup2(devnull, 2)
        local dir = wifi.wpa_supplicant_dir()
        local iface = posix.basename(dir)
        iface = string.gsub(iface, "wpa_supplicant%-",'')
        posix.exec('/usr/sbin/iw', {'dev', iface, 'link'})
        posix._exit(-1)
    elseif cpid > 0 then
        --parent reads from pipe, close write end
        posix.close(w)
        local buf = ''
        while true do
            local tmp = posix.read(r, 100)
            if tmp ~= nil and #tmp > 0 then
                buf = buf .. tmp
            else
                break
            end
        end
        -- TODO, check exit value, to see if entry exists or not
        while posix.wait(cpid) ~= cpid do print("waiting in wpa_supplicant_status") end
        print("status is "..buf)
        if string.find(buf, "Connected to", 1, true) then
            return true
        else
            return false
        end
    end
end
```

This is what I understand what I have to do(to just get output):

1. create a single pipe
2. fork

   - if child,

     1. close read end of pipe
     2. dup2(write_end, stdout)
     3. exec() to desired process
   - if parent

     1. close write end of pipe
     2. do blocking reads to read end of pipe, till you get a 0 byte read, which means the child process has terminated, closing the pipe

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the answers in this question [How do you construct a read-write pipe with lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242572/how-do-you-construct-a-read-write-pipe-with-lua)

to get an idea of the difficulties to implement this. One thing that strikes me is that nobody seems to be able to get it to work with only **one** child process.

However, In the example you give, it seems you only want to get the output of the command, so I would suggest simply doing this:

```
function os.capture(cmd)
    local f = assert(io.popen(cmd, 'r'))
    local s = assert(f:read('*a'))
    f:close()
    return s
end

function wifi.wpa_supplicant_status()
    local dir = wifi.wpa_supplicant_dir()
    local iface = posix.basename(dir):gsub("wpa_supplicant%-",'')
    local cmd = ('/usr/sbin/iw dev %s link'):format(iface)
    local buf = os.capture(cmd)
    return buf:find("Connected to", 1, true) ~= nil
end
```

This is not even tested, but you should get the idea.