# Strange io.popen behaviour in lua

Tags: nginx, lua, popen, openresty

I have lua block in nginx config, which checks for redis-server connection and if 4 java-processes are up, and then returns 200 or 500 status accordingly to this checks.

```
location = /healthcheck {

    content_by_lua_block {
        local redis = require "resty.redis"
        local red = redis:new()  
        red:set_timeout(1000)
        local ok, err = red:connect("127.0.0.1", 6379)
        if not ok then
            ngx.status = 500
            return
        end


        local ps = io.popen("/bin/ps aux |grep -c '[j]ava.*63'")
        local output = tostring(ps:read('*a'))
        ps:close()
        if string.match(output, '4') then
            ngx.status = 200
        else
            ngx.status = 500
        end
    }

}
```

But periodically `output` variable takes `nil` value, while it shouldn't. Just can't get why it happens.

Thanks in advance, comrades.

**UPD:**

Using `tonumber` fails on

`bad argument #2 to 'tonumber' (number expected, got string)`

Updated location config:

```
   location = /healthcheck {

        content_by_lua_block {
            local redis = require "resty.redis"
            local red = redis:new()
            red:set_timeout(1000)
            local ok, err = red:connect("127.0.0.1", 6379)
            if not ok then
                ngx.status = 500
                return
            end

            local ps = io.popen("/bin/ps aux |grep -c '[j]ava.*63'")
            local output = tonumber(ps:read())
            ps:close()
            if (output == 4) then
                ngx.status = 200
            else
                ngx.status = 500
            end
        }

    }
```

**UPD2:**

Logging to nginx error (with tostring) prints next:

```
grep: write error: Broken pipe
2016/04/19 17:54:48 [error] 301#0: *5 [lua] content_by_lua(healthcheck.conf:33):20: OUTPUT:nil
```

**UPD3:**

Using command `grep -c '[j]ava.*63' <(/bin/ps aux)` to avoid the use of pipe:

`local ps = io.popen("grep -c '[j]ava.*63' <(/bin/ps aux)")`

getting next error:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `grep -c '[j]ava.*63' <(/bin/ps aux)'
```

Comment: I've tested it by printing variable to nginx log, and there weren't any double quotes, as far as I remember.

Comment: does it return the string nil or the value nil?
why do you use tostring anyway? read already returns a string

Comment: Just guess, move local ps = io.popen(...) line in the beginning of content_by_lua_block. Will it change something?

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler nope, it's useless. I also tried `tonumber`, but it prints `bad argument #2 to 'tonumber' (number expected, got string)`

Comment: popen use sh, not bash,  process substitution doesn't work

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler check my (working, I suppose) solution below, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1242639/3906452) answer and some testing next config do the job:

```
location = /healthcheck {

    content_by_lua_block {
        local redis = require "resty.redis"
        local red = redis:new()
        red:set_timeout(1000)
        local ok, err = red:connect("127.0.0.1", 6379)
        if not ok then
            ngx.status = 500
            return
        end

        local ps = io.popen("/bin/ps aux >/tmp/ps.out", "w")
        ps:close()
        local ps = io.popen("grep -c '[j]ava.*63' /tmp/ps.out")
        local output = tostring(ps:read())
        ps:close()
        if string.match(output, '4') then
            ngx.status = 200
        else
            ngx.status = 500
        end

    }

}
```

Comment: @Prashanth any proofs? It WORKED for me about 3 years ago. And, you know, the things, they're changing, so maybe it won't work for now. Maybe if you'd be more specific, someone would help you with your issue to make it work the way you want it to.

Comment: Hi @cardinal-gray, I'm trying to get the output of my shell script but it doesn't give me any output or it doesn't even error. 

It runs fine when i run `curl -I http://localhost:9001``` but it's not creating that ps.out file on in temp directory.

Comment: error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    server {
        listen 9001;
        location /tmp {
           default_type text/html;
           content_by_lua '
                ngx.say("<p>hello, world</p>")
           ';
        }

        location / {
            content_by_lua_block {
  local ps = io.popen("/bin/ps aux >/tmp/ps.out", "w")
         ps:close()
         local ps = io.popen("grep -c '[j]ava.*63' /tmp/ps.out")
         local output = tostring(ps:read())
         ps:close()
            }
        }

    }
}
```