# Why this io.open read return nil?

Tags: powershell, lua

```
        local script = [[
            [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
            Invoke-RestMethod https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MyAcc/MyBranch/main/blabla.lua  -Method Get -Headers @{"Authorization" = "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}
            
            ]]
        local pipe = io.popen("powershell -command -","w"):write(script)
        local result = pipe:read('*all')
        pipe:close()
        print(result)
```

When i run this code it show the raw file from github but the print(result) return as nil why is that ?

This is the error i got and the nil value afterward

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You are opening a pipe that can only be written to (`"w"`). Lua pipes are one-way pipes. See [the reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-io.popen): You can *either* open a `"r"` or `"w"` pipe, but a pipe can't be both at the same time. Thus reading [fails by returning `nil`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-file:read) because there is nothing to read. See also [this question on implementing two-way pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242572/how-do-you-construct-a-read-write-pipe-with-lua).

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, i already look the link  you point on how to implementing two way pipes, but i still dont get it how to implement that on my code cause i need to write then read the result afterward